# why nav bar wont scratch to 100% width as told?

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to html style, and I want to make a top nav bar like this site(stackoverflow.com) that will be 100% width and on top of the browser. Here is what I tried:

```
<style>
body{text-align:center;}

.wrapper{width:80%;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #497093;
    border-color: #3e5f7d;
}
#nav-bar{
    width:100% !important; <-- here I make the nav-bar 100% width.
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

But it will still fixed as 80% width :-(

How can I make this work?
[image]

Here is the snippet of html

```
<body class="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="nav-bar"> 
    </div>
...
...
</body>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML as well. If I had to guess I could say you have your nav bar inside your wrapper, so nav width would be 100% of 80%of the page.

Comment: yes, just as you presumed, .wrapper is the style of `body`, thus nav bar is also inside wrapper

Comment: I think your making the nav-bar 100% of your wrapper, so it cannot be larger than 80%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looked at the image and it is as my comment said. You have your `nav` inside your `wrapper`. Move it outside and it will be 100% width of the window.

It was 100% of the parent (`wrapper`) and the parent had 80% width.

---

**Edit**

In your case you have a class on body so any child element will be scaled from 80% width. I would recommend wrapping the content in a `div` and moving the `nav` outside of that wrapper.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.nav {
  background: red;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">We can go 100%!</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  Content Here
</div>
```

Comment: But I want to make the whole page 80% width. So can I make the total body 80% except the nav-bar. ie make a override style of this nav-bar?

Comment: seems a charming answer, how can't I thought a way like that, thanks!

Comment: @armnotstrong No problem, any questions feel free to comment again.